# How to set correct sizes from Adobe Illustrator / Sketch to flutter?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, size, flutter-layout, devicepixelratio

I've created a design using Sketch and AI (adobe illustrator) and basing on that I've created the structure on flutter.
The problem there is that the pixels and pt sizes on Sketch do not corresponding to the size of pixels (?) in Flutter.
I know this happens because of pixelRatio but, there is a way to replicate exactly the same UI being pixel perfect?
Is there a formula I can apply?
Thanks in advance